# How can i get the writing in a text in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Text widget that contains two rows of text. I need to get the row when i click on it. For example if i click on the second row of text ı should get the only second row of text. I tried to bind it but it didnt work.

And also there is an another problem. Bind function only works for one time. If i click on the Text widget second time it does not work. My code is getting every row of text not that i clicked on.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

clicked = StringVar()


text = Text(root,height = 10, width = 30,relief = SUNKEN )
text.grid(row = 0, column = 0,padx = 20,pady = 20)
text.insert(END,"Oda the Elder\nJohn the Baptist")

def getelement(event):
    for t in range(1,3):
        get_ = text.get(f"{t}.0",f"{t+1}.0")
        print(get_)

text.bind("<FocusIn>",getelement)

but = Button(root,text = "click")
but.grid(row = 1, column = 0)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with the Text box as everything is inside that text box only. The lines are theoretically defined. You want to use a Listbox

**Syntax**

Here is the simple syntax to create this widget −

```
w = Listbox ( master, option, ... )
```

```
Parameters
master − This represents the parent window.

options − Here is the list of most commonly used options for this widget. These options can be used as key-value pairs separated by commas.
```

Below is an example of code:

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()

Lb1 = Listbox(top)
Lb1.insert(1, "Python")
Lb1.insert(2, "Perl")
Lb1.insert(3, "C")
Lb1.insert(4, "PHP")
Lb1.insert(5, "JSP")
Lb1.insert(6, "Ruby")
def items_selected(event):
    """ handle item selected event
    """
    # get selected indices
    selected_indices = Lb1.curselection()
    # get selected items
    selected_langs = ",".join([Lb1.get(i) for i in selected_indices])
    msg = f'You selected: {selected_langs}'

    print(msg)


Lb1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', items_selected)
Lb1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

[More details](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_listbox.htm)

Comment: Is thıs work with bind function, i mean when click on 'C' am i be able to get third row only?

Comment: @omneer I Updated the code, if that's what you wanted please accept the answer

Comment: _"You can't do this with the Text box"_ - that is a false statement.

Comment: @BryanOakley Would love to see how it can be done

Comment: @EXODIA see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66616443/7432) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the button click event (`<1>`). Within the function you can get the index based on the x/y of the mouse at the time of the click. From that you can get the text of that whole line by modifying the index with "linestart" and "lineend".

The function would look something like this:

```
def getelement(event):
    index = event.widget.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y}")
    text = event.widget.get(f"{index} linestart", f"{index} lineend")
    print(text)
```

The binding would look like this:

```
text.bind("<1>",getelement)
```

Comment: If I am clicking somewhere downside from second line then still second line is being printed

Comment: @EXODIA: yes, that's what this code does. You have all the data you need to be able to handle that edge case if you want. You can get the coordinates of the last line, and you can compare that to the coordinates of the click.